# How to manipulate the responds in http angular

Tags: angular, http, http-post

I do make a app in Angular (2), and I need handle the response of a REST service.
For example, i make a POST to a endpoint and this endpoint respond with a observable. In the backend, the endpoint if everything went well returns a 400, but has some settings for some custom codes. What I want is you can trigger events in the UI with Angular depending on the code you receive. How can I handle it?

```
postClient(modelClient: Client, modelAssociation?: Association) {
    const req = this.httpClient
      .post(`http://localhost:5001/api/client`, modelClient, {
        headers: this.getHeaders()
      })
      .subscribe(
      next => {
        if (modelAssociation) {
          this.postAssociation(modelAssociation);
        }
        console.log(`Se envio la Asociacion.`);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(`Ocurrio un error: ${error}`);
      },
      () => {
        console.log(`Request Complete.`);
      });
  }
```

It's my code for a service POST. I think use the next atributte of the observer for user the 200 OK code, and the error for other things.
My question is if with the complete I can analyze the response of the POST service? What would be the strategy to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in use directly the new Http service of Angular. It automatically allows me to manipulate the next of an Observable as a response object.